# Django error - didn't return an HttpResponse object

Tags: django, httpresponse

in my main application folder, the URLs.py has the following code.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
    # (r'^catalog/$', home),
    (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        { 'document_root' : 'C:/SHIYAM/Personal/SuccessOwl/SOWL0.1/SOWL/SOWL/static'}),
    # (r'^admin/', include('django.contrib.admin.urls')),
    (r'^catalog/', include('CATALOG.urls')),
    (r'^accounts/', include('registration.urls')),
    (r'^$', main_page),
)
```

I have a seperate app (Folder) called "CATALOG" and it's URLs.py has the following code:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('SOWL.catalog.views',
    (r'^$', 'index', { 'template_name':'catalog/index.html'}, 'catalog_home'),
    (r'^category/(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'show_category', {'template_name':'catalog/category.html'},'catalog_category'),
    (r'^product/(?P<product_slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'show_product', {'template_name':'catalog/product.html'},'catalog_product'),
    (r'^enter_product/$',enter_product),
)
```

Under catalog folder, I have forms.py

```
from django import forms
from CATALOG.models import Product

class ProductAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product

def clean_price(self):
    if self.cleaned_data['price'] <= 0:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Price must be greater than zero.')
    return self.cleaned_data['price']

class Product_Form(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label='name', max_length=30)
    slug = forms.SlugField(label='Unique Name for the URL', max_length=30)
    brand = forms.CharField(label='Unique Name for the URL', max_length=30)
    price = forms.DecimalField(label='Price',max_digits=9,decimal_places=2)
    old_price = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=9,decimal_places=2,initial=0.00)
    quantity = forms.IntegerField()
    description = forms.CharField()
    meta_keywords = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    meta_description = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    categories = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    user = forms.IntegerField()

    prepopulated_fields = {'slug' : ('name',)}
```

and views.py

```
from CATALOG.forms import *
def enter_product(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.create_user(
                username=form.clean_data['username'],
                password=form.clean_data['password1'],
                email=form.clean_data['email']
            )
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            form = RegistrationForm()
        variables = RequestContext(request, {
            'form': form
        })

        return render_to_response(
            'catalog/enter_product.html',
            variables
        )
```

and under "\templates\catalog" folder, I have "enter_product.html", which has the following code:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}blah{% endblock %}
{% block head %}blah{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<form method="post" action=".">
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Enter" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

but when I go to localhost:8000/catalog/enter_product/ it says:

The view CATALOG.views.enter_product didn't return an HttpResponse object.

why is that? Thanks for your help.

- Toronto

Answer (score 0):

Your `return render_to_response...` is indented inside of `if request.method == 'POST'`. So if it is not a post, the view function returns nothing. Try unindenting your return statement by one level.

Comment: from CATALOG.forms import *
def enter_product(request):
 if request.method == 'POST':
  form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
  if form.is_valid():
   user = User.objects.create_user(
    username=form.clean_data['username'],
    password=form.clean_data['password1'],
    email=form.clean_data['email']
   )
   return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
 else:
  form = RegistrationForm()
 variables = RequestContext(request, {
   'form': form
  })